# Implementing an android service that reads a button sensor input on Arduino through bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-sensors, arduino-uno, android-hardware

I am trying to connect a button sensor on Arduino 101, to an Android App.

The idea is to implement an app which connects to a Bluetooth hardware button on Arduino and then runs a service in the background that constantly listens for a Bluetooth broadcast. If the button is clicked a Bluetooth signal is transmitted through Arduino and the service should catch the signal and open the app.

I used the official Android documentation for Bluetooth LE Generic Attribute Profile (GATT) to transmit arbitrary data fro Arduino to background service. My service is able to connect to the bluetooth signal and disconnect, but unable to detect the button click.

Could someone please help me ?

This is the code for the Bluetooth Listener Service

```
private final BluetoothGattCallback mGattCallback = new      BluetoothGattCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status, int newState) {
            String intentAction;
        if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED) {
            intentAction = ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED;
            mConnectionState = STATE_CONNECTED;
            broadcastUpdate(intentAction);
            Log.i(TAG, "Connected to GATT server.");
            // Attempts to discover services after successful connection.
            Log.i(TAG, "Attempting to start service discovery:" +
                    mBluetoothGatt.discoverServices());

        } else if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED) {
            intentAction = ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED;
            mConnectionState = STATE_DISCONNECTED;
            Log.i(TAG, "Disconnected from GATT server.");
            broadcastUpdate(intentAction);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) {
        if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
            broadcastUpdate(ACTION_GATT_SERVICES_DISCOVERED);
        } else {
            Log.w(TAG, "onServicesDiscovered received: " + status);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCharacteristicRead(BluetoothGatt gatt,
                                     BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic,
                                     int status) {
        if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
            broadcastUpdate(ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE, characteristic);

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCharacteristicChanged(BluetoothGatt gatt,
                                        BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
        broadcastUpdate(ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE, characteristic);
    }
};

private void broadcastUpdate(final String action) {
    final Intent intent = new Intent(action);
    sendBroadcast(intent);
}

private void broadcastUpdate(final String action,
                             final BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
    final Intent intent = new Intent(action);
    final byte[] data = characteristic.getValue();
    if (data != null && data.length > 0) {
            final StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(data.length);
            for(byte byteChar : data)
                stringBuilder.append(String.format("%02X ", byteChar));
        System.out.println(stringBuilder);
            intent.putExtra(EXTRA_DATA,"\n" + stringBuilder.toString());
    }
    sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

The following is the BroadcastReceiver inside another service. These two services are communicating with each other.

```
 private final BroadcastReceiver mGattUpdateReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        final String action = intent.getAction();
        if (BluetoothLeService.ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED.equals(action)) {
            mConnected = true;
        } else if (BluetoothLeService.ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED.equals(action)) {
            mConnected = false;

        } else if (BluetoothLeService.ACTION_GATT_SERVICES_DISCOVERED.equals(action)) {
            // Show all the supported services and characteristics on the user interface.
            displayGattServices(mBluetoothLeService.getSupportedGattServices());

        } else if (BluetoothLeService.ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE.equals(action)) {
           System.out.println(intent.getStringExtra(BluetoothLeService.EXTRA_DATA));

        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Hey is the connection okay? are you able to send data between arduino and android? Are you able to serial print any data transferred from Android?

Comment: Yes, Arduino code is working. I am able to transfer data from my arduino in an Android activity but not in a service.